# How to find and update the first row of duplicated rows with SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm looking for a good way to do the following:

We have a table `Accounts` where some records have accidentally been imported twice, so they are duplicates. I have found that I can select all rows which are imported twice with the following query:

```
select name, vatnumber from Accounts 
WHERE IsDeleted='false'
GROUP BY name, vatnumber
HAVING count(*) > 1
```

Basically: if the `name` and the `vatnumber` are the same, they are duplicates.

This gives me all the records that have been imported twice. Now I'm looking for a way to get the first Id of every double record so I can do something like:

```
UPDATE Accounts SET IsDeleted='true'
WHERE Id = (select id ...)
```

So basically, I'm trying to update the first row of every double record, so there are no more doubles. Can anyone please point me in the right direction? I haven't got the faintest clue on how to start doing this besides doing manual labour and I'm guessing there is a much easier way.

Sample data:

```
Id     VatNumber     Name
 1     BE10128292    Microsoft
 2     BE99292200    Google
 3     BE10128292    Microsoft
 4     BE99292200    Some other company
 5     BE99292200    Google
```

Desired result:

```
Id     VatNumber     Name
 1     BE10128292    Microsoft
 2     BE99292200    Google
```

It doesn't matter whether I get the first `Microsoft` or the last `Microsoft` record really. Ideally, it would be the first though.

Comment: Updated my question with sample data & desired output

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I remove duplicate rows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18932/how-can-i-remove-duplicate-rows)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try below using `CTE` :

```
;WITH cte
     AS (
     SELECT *,
            ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY vatnumber ORDER BY id) rn
     FROM <tablename>)
     SELECT Id,
            VatNumber,
            Name
     FROM cte
     WHERE rn = 1;
```

**Desired Result :**

```
Id     VatNumber     Name
 1     BE10128292    Microsoft
 2     BE99292200    Google
```

Comment: Thanks! This was the solution I went with!

Answer (score 3):

This should do the job, run the sample and check the output. It Updates your `IsDeleted` flag where your duplicates are found but uses the `MIN(ID)` to target the first row only.

```
CREATE TABLE #dupes
(
    id INT,
    vatNo NVARCHAR(20),
    name NVARCHAR(20),
    isDeleted BIT
        DEFAULT 0
);

INSERT INTO #dupes
(
    id,
    vatNo,
    name
)
VALUES
(1, 'BE10128292', 'Microsoft'),
(2, 'BE99292200', 'Google'),
(3, 'BE10128292', 'Microsoft'),
(4, 'BE99292200', 'Some other company'),
(5, 'BE99292200', 'Google');


UPDATE #dupes
SET isDeleted = 1
WHERE id IN (
                SELECT MIN(id) MinId
                FROM #dupes
                WHERE isDeleted = 0
                GROUP BY name,
                         vatNo
                HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
            );

SELECT *
FROM #dupes AS d;

DROP TABLE #dupes;
```

**Produces:**

```
id  vatNo       name                isDeleted
1   BE10128292  Microsoft           1
2   BE99292200  Google              1
3   BE10128292  Microsoft           0
4   BE99292200  Some other company  0
5   BE99292200  Google              0
```

So specific to your database, the query would be:

```
UPDATE Accounts 
SET isDeleted = 1
WHERE Id IN (
                SELECT MIN(id) MinId
                FROM Accounts
                WHERE isDeleted = 0
                GROUP BY name,
                         vatNo
                HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
            );
```

Comment: This IS best Solution.Good

Comment: @Mr.Bhosale considering he asked for an update query, i'd have to agree.

Answer (score 1):

Check This.

```
with  CTE  as
( 
select *,ROW_NUMBER()over(partition by vatnumber,name order by ID )rowid  
from #tableName
)
select * from CTE where rowid='2' // here you can change RowID 2 or 1
```

Check Demo [Here](http://rextester.com/HGJCYE4616)

Answer (score 1):

Try `CTE` as below :

```
WITH CTE
         AS (
         SELECT vatnumber,
                name,
                ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY vatnumber,
                                               name ORDER BY ID) rowid,
                IsDeleted
         FROM Accounts
         WHERE IsDeleted = 'false')
         UPDATE CTE
           SET
               IsDeleted = 'true'
         WHERE rowid > 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
;WITH  removeDup  as

( 

SELECT *,ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY vatnumber,name ORDER BY ID ) DupId  

from Accounts

)

DELETE from removeDup where DupId=2
```